# custom function check type of javascipt

Tags: javascript

I see a function check type in javascript but I don't understand how it works

```
const typeOf = value => Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8,-1)
typeOf(1) //=> number
typeOf("a") //=> string
typeOf([1]) //=> array
typeOf(()=> {}) //=> function
```

Please help me explain

Comment: Which part don't you understand? [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.prototype.toString` is similar to a big switch statement on the value it's called on. What it does [is](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring):

```
1. If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".
2. If the this value is null, return "[object Null]".
3. Let O be ! ToObject(this value).
4. Let isArray be ? IsArray(O).
5. If isArray is true, let builtinTag be "Array".
6. Else if O has a [[ParameterMap]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Arguments".
7. Else if O has a [[Call]] internal method, let builtinTag be "Function".
8. Else if O has an [[ErrorData]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Error".
9. Else if O has a [[BooleanData]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Boolean".
10. Else if O has a [[NumberData]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Number".
11. Else if O has a [[StringData]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "String".
12. Else if O has a [[DateValue]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Date".
13. Else if O has a [[RegExpMatcher]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "RegExp".
14. Else, let builtinTag be "Object".
15. Let tag be ? Get(O, @@toStringTag).
16. If Type(tag) is not String, set tag to builtinTag.
17. Return the string-concatenation of "[object ", tag, and "]".
```

It essentially iterates through different types of language objects and will create a string corresponding to the one that it matches. For example, if a number is passed, the string generated is `"Number"`.

This string is then concatenated to produce

```
[object Number]
        ^^^^^^
```

where the ^^^ section varies depending on what sort of argument was passed.

Doing `.slice(8,-1)` is like reversing step 17 - it takes the substring starting from index 8 (right after the space) to the next to last character in the string (inclusive) - so the substring that is extracted is `"Number"` or `"Boolean"` or something similar.